# Continuity Problem, prove that $f(r)=r^{2013}$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $f$ : $R$ → $R$ be differentiable such that for all $x \in R$,

$$f(1 − f(x)) = 1 − x^9.$$

If $f(1) = 0$ and $f′(1) < 0$, then prove that there exists $r \in R$ such that $f(r) = r^{2013}$.

How should I prove it? Any suggests to solve. Thank you.

Comment: Another beautiful question closed unnecessarily.

Comment: To complete the idea that David told you below. We have seen that the function only vanishes at $x=1$. Since the derivative at $x=1$ is negative, that means that to the right of $x=1$ (near it) it must take negative values and positive to the left. Since the function never vanishes again these signs are constant all over the right and the left of $x=1$. This means that $f(0)>0$. Now we compare $f$ and $x^{2013}$ in the interval $[0,1]$. They are both continuous and at $x=1$ $f(1)=0<1=1^{2013}$, at $x=0$ $f(0)>0=0^{2013}$. Therefore there is some $r\in[0,1]$ where they cross (where they are =).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  If $f(x)=0$ then
$$1-x^9=f(1-f(x))=f(1)=0\ ,$$
and so $f$ has no roots except for $x=1$.  Combine this with the other given information in order to find out something useful about $f(0)$.

Comment: @EricTowers: no, I have shown that if $f(x)=0$ then $x$ can only be $1$.  It is true that I haven't actually shown that $x=1$ is a root - conceivably there might be no roots at all - but in any case it is given that $x=1$ is a root.

Comment: Got it.  Should head to bed.  Retracting comment.